# tidy -clean is not removing <font> tags

Tags: tidy, htmltidy

Hi I am using Tidy in command line. everything is working fine but -clean y is not working.

```
tidy -m sampleon.html --clean y --doctype "strict"
```

after conversion there is no much difference. it has still lot of  tags in it.

Answer (score 0):

After spending couple of hours I've found the solution. the actual syntax for this command is

```
tidy -c -m  --doctype "strict" sampleon.html
```